# Strange problem with storage put on laravel

Tags: laravel

I pushed some project on bit bucket, cloned for new branch on same pc with different name. Pulled same on vps. It works on vps and main project, but one for branch doesn't work.

```
Storage::put('filename.txt', 'Content', 'public');
```

This returns true but I get no files in `APPNAME/STORAGE/APP/PUBLIC/` nor anywhere in storage...

Anyone know why? (I am poor cant buy better pc right now)

Comment: What does your filesystem permissions look like? Anything in your error log?

Comment: I have no logs for now. Where can I check for permission? I tried giving 777 to storage if you mean about that

Comment: try git pull and try again..